# Serial port read interval not applying in C++

Tags: c++, serial-port

Here's my entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
   //? create the serial port file with read and write perms
   HANDLE hPort = CreateFileW(L"COM3",
                              GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                              0,
                              0,
                              OPEN_EXISTING,
                              0,
                              0);

   if (hPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      std::cout << "INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE/6\n";
      if (GetLastError() == 2) {
         std::cout << "serial port doesn't exist. error code: 2/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND\n";
      } else {
         std::cout << "error occured with serial port file creation (CreateFileW). error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
      }
      CloseHandle(hPort);
   } else {
      std::cout << "serial port created successfully (probably)\n";
   }

   DCB port_conf;
   int err = GetCommState(hPort, &port_conf);
   if (err == 0) {
      std::cout << "GetCommState failed. error code: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
      CloseHandle(hPort);
   }
   port_conf.BaudRate = 9600;
   port_conf.Parity = NOPARITY;
   port_conf.ByteSize = 8;
   port_conf.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
   port_conf.DCBlength = sizeof(port_conf);
   
   err = SetCommState(hPort, &port_conf);

   COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts_conf;
   timeouts_conf.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
   timeouts_conf.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
   timeouts_conf.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
   timeouts_conf.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
   timeouts_conf.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;

   err = SetCommTimeouts(hPort, &timeouts_conf);


   DWORD buffer_size_read;
   char buffer_read[512]{};
   int buffer_read_size;
   char buffer_read_last[512]{};
   
   while (1){
      ReadFile(hPort,
               buffer_read,
               512,
               &buffer_size_read,
               0);

      std::cout << buffer_read;

      // if (buffer_read_last != buffer_read) {
      //    std::cout << buffer_read;
      // }

      // buffer_read_size = strlen(buffer_read);
      // for (int i = 0; i <= buffer_read_size; i++) {
      //    buffer_read_last[i] = buffer_read[i];
      // }

      if (GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) != 0) {
         break;
      }

   }

   CloseHandle(hPort);
}
```

The problem with it is that everything is spit out too fast into cout. I made a miserable attempt at limiting this (it is commented out), but the program just doesn't do anything then. Another attempt was using the `timeouts_conf.ReadIntervalTimeout`, which Microsoft describes this way:

> The maximum time allowed to elapse before the arrival of the next byte on the communications line, in milliseconds. If the interval between the arrival of any two bytes exceeds this amount, the ReadFile operation is completed and any buffered data is returned. A value of zero indicates that interval time-outs are not used.

but it didn't change anything. The serial port is continuously receiving data from a microcontroller in which **I will not** do the limiting for a pretty specific reason.

I need some sort of reliable way of *not spitting everything out to cout at the speed of light*. Thanks in advance

Comment: *I need some sort of reliable way of not spitting everything out to cout at the speed of light.* -- Why not save the data to a queue, and then dump out the queue to `cout` when the queue is full?

Comment: Warning: `std::cout << buffer_read;` expects `buffer_read` to be null terminated, something I don't think you guarantee.

Comment: Do you understand the implication of the word "maximum" in that documentation?

Comment: Yes, `std::cout.write(buffer_read, buffer_size_read);` is what you really want.

Comment: @BenVoigt I suppose I do. Setting it to 1000 didn't change anything. If I'm getting something wrong I'd love to hear an explaination

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That would introduce a delay, not a rate limit.  For any finite length data structure, the rate of the output can't be less than the rate at the input.  A queue can help, but it needs to be allowed to grow and output needs to be done based on a clock not based on "it's full".

Comment: @user4581301 Should I add a '\0' in my Arduino's code? It currently looks like this: `sprintf(pos, "POS%c%2.2f\n", 43, wheel_pos);
    Serial.print(pos);`

Comment: @purplishflame: "Maximum allowed" means that shorter times (faster transfer) is possible, it can just no longer be a longer time (slower transfer) than the limit you set (because the function will return with less data instead of waiting for a longer time).

Comment: @purplishflame -- *Should I add a '\0' in my microcontroller's code?* -- Don't put nulls in data that may have embedded nulls already in the stream.  That will at the very least, confuse things, and worse, corrupt the data that came in.  Imagine if a CRC check was done to ensure that the original data that was sent is what you received, and you inadvertently (or on purpose) stuck null(s) in that data.  That CRC check would then fail.

Comment: Since Windows and its PCs are not real-time systems, serial port communication cannot be performed according to strict timing without the assistance of special hardware and special device drivers. It is very unlikely that your requirements will be fulfilled with general purpose hardware and general purpose software.

Comment: And a null at the data source might not be good enough. Say the message is 15 bytes, including null, and for one reason or another there's a bit of a slow down so the `ReadFile` call times out after receiving 13 bytes. Ka-boom. If you have a message protocol with a length or terminator, you need to make sure you get length bytes or the terminator before you do anything.